# Gunicorn "error: unrecognized arguments: --log-file--"

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my django application to heroku, but every single time I try, I see this error in my logs:

```
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --log-file--
```

But my **Procfile** looks like this (I haven't forgotten to save it or anything)

```
web: gunicorn post_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

I can't really put my eye on anything that may be a cause of that error except these few lines at Heroku

> This app is using free dynos
>
> web gunicorn post_project.wsgi --log-file--

Comment: *I haven't forgotten to save it or anything* - perhaps you need to check in changes to git or push changes.

Comment: @Alasdair I thank you wholeheartedly, I would have spent much more time to figure this out if not you

Answer (score 1):

It is not the correct way to use it as `--log-file-`. It is `--log-file`.